# How to use a variable value in a colorscheme

Tags: colorscheme, highlight, variables

I'm trying to make a colorscheme configurable where I define the style in a variable defined in my `.vimrc`.

```
let g:plugin_style='<vim-highlighting-style>'
```

Then in the colorscheme I'm doing:

```
highlight! StyleName g:plugin_style
```

This doesn't work, `hightlight!` uses the literal `g:plugin_style`.

I tried as well to use exec

```
exec 'highlight! StyleName ' . g:plugin_style
```

This doesn't work neither, StyleName is not known afterwards.

How to do this in vimscript?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2211738/4194289) seems to indicate that you can use the `exec` syntax. I may be wrong but I guess the problem comes from the fact you define your variable after setting your colorscheme? Also I guess it's a typo but your definition line should be `let g:plugin_style='VirtualNOS'`

Comment: Also I'm not a colorscheme expert but are you sure that `highlight! StyleName VirtualNOS` makes sense? Shouldn't it be something of the form `highlight! StyleName term=bold ctermfg=Cyan guifg=#80a0ff gui=bold`?

Comment: The less "logic" you put in your colorscheme the better it will work.

Comment: I asked this question for the HighlightCursorWords-plugin (https://github.com/pboettch/vim-highlight-cursor-words). Which creates a new style for itself which should be configurable from .vimrc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Jamessan suggested in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2211738/4194289), using `execute` should work properly.

Firs the variable should be defined like this:

```
let g:plugin_style='term=bold ctermfg=Cyan guifg=#80a0ff gui=bold'
```

See [`:h highlight-args`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#highlight%2Dargs) for the values that this variable can take.

Then simply use:

```
execute 'highlight [default] {group-name} ' . g:plugin_style
```

Finally an important note is to define the variable before you call your colorscheme otherwise the colorscheme cannot know the value of the variable.